# IE not playback mp3 from php script

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have problem with playback audio just only in IE. 
The console does not show an error. I get file from php script and set this headers:

```
    $mime_type = "audio/mpeg";
    header("Content-Type: {$mime_type}");
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
```

In js:

```
    audio.src = source;
    audio.load();
    audio.addEventListener('canplay', function(){
        audio.play();
    }, true);
```

In `source` path to php script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Add this meta tag to the head:
```

> < meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

```
and also

Try
```

> audio/vnd.wave

```
because some browser do attempt content fixing wrong MIME types.
```